# How to fix permalinks not working with Vagrant and Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Vagrant to build up a little Wordpress development VM. When I select permalinks (postname) then the page from an article doesn't load. However, when I select the standard link (i.e page id) all is working good.
I've used the service PuPHPet to build the VM.

My settings can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/pYERZ7Xy)

I am using Wordpress 3.9.1 and Apache2
I've enabled mod_rewrite be executing:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

And my .htaccess file from Wordpress is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /svisa/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /svisa/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

it has the following permissions and ownership:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant www-data   248 May 30 14:52 .htaccess
```

My virtualhost file for the site (`/var/www/svisa/`) can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/LayWVfJt).

from my host computer, I browse to the site via adress: `http://wpdev-vm/svisa/`
where `wpdev-vm` is the name of the vm.

***Does anybody know what I am missing to make the permalinks work?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

In the default apache configuration, under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, where mine is called `15-default.conf`

This was declared under the document root:

```
   <Directory "/var/www">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

I had to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. Thus you'll get the following:

```
   <Directory "/var/www">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

After that, the permalinks started working.

Answer (score 2):

The (correct) answer above says that you need to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in your xxx-default.conf file found in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory.

However, in my vagrant box (precise64) none of the allowOverride or `<Directory /var/www/>...` code was present to begin with in the default.conf file.

I ended up having to add all of it between the VirtualHost tags, like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Other stuff
    <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And then having to restart apache, like below, for it to work.

`sudo service apache2 restart`